# How to capitalize string in fish shell?

Tags: string, shell, fish, capitalization, capitalize

I got the following text:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.

That I want to capitalize, i.e. uppercase first letter of every word.

#### Expected result

> Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet, Consectetur Adipisicing Elit.

#### Bash equivalent

Using bash, I was using a parameter expansion:

```
function to-lower() { echo "$@" |tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' ; }

function capitalize() {
    input="$(to-lower "$@")"
    for i in $input; do
        cap=$(echo -n "${i:0:1}" | tr "[:lower:]" "[:upper:]")
        echo -n "${cap}${i:1} "
    done
    echo
}
```

#### Question

How do I do that in a fish-way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fish currently doesn't have any tools to do this (in a release), so assuming you have GNU sed you can do this:

```
function capitalize
    echo $argv | sed 's/[^ _-]*/\u&/g'
end
```

There are also a variety of other tools, you can also do it with e.g. python or by calling bash from fish, the point is that there is no way to either extract a substring or replace a character with fish builtins.

In the next fish release, you'll be able to use `string sub -l 1 $i` to extract the first character.

Comment: I'm really not fond of the `string` util, it's really verbose yet obscure. I will probably stick to external tool solution as it's shell-agnostic.

Comment: I'm [porting my existing bash/zsh dotfiles to fish](https://github.com/edouard-lopez/dotfiles), see `.my-posixrc` and `.my-fishrc`

Comment: @faho IDK why but this solution doesn't work for me. Fish v2.3.1 and gnu-sed 4.2.2

Comment: Yeah, that regexp was broken. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `string replace` with regular expressions to achieve this:

```
$ string replace -r -a '\b([\w])' '\U$0' "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit."
Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet, Consectetur Adipisicing Elit.
```

[image: Wait, forgot to escape a space. Wheeeeee[taptaptap]eeeeee.]

Comment: This is the correct answer. I'm surprised the answer would ever be to use `sed` for a fish question. I always recommend `string`.

Answer (score 1):

Solution using external tool (from [commandlinefu](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/9230/capitalize-first-letter-of-each-word-in-a-string))

```
function capitalize
    set input "$argv"
    echo "$input" | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' | sed 's/\(^\| \)\([a-z]\)/\1\u\2/g'
end
```

#### Usage

```
capitalize "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit."
```

> Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet, Consectetur Adipisicing Elit.

Answer (score 0):

None of the previous solutions work for me. It seems that `sed` doesn't works well in my machine. If anyone experiences any similar problem this is the workaround I've finally used:

```
function title_case -a string
  set -l matches (string match -r -a '\b[a-z]' $string)

  for match in $matches
    set -l upper (echo $match | tr a-z A-Z)
    set string (echo (string replace -r '\b[a-z]' $upper $string))
  end

  echo $string
end
```

Only works in **fish 2.3.0 or newer** versions due I'm using the `string` builtin

Comment: I've tried it now and it seems to works as expected, the user wants a variation of Title Case - without exceptions for the, and... - and that's how this function works. Maybe what you want is a something like a Upper case function? if that's not the case what version of fish shell are you using?

Comment: yep, my mistake. though it was TOUPPER.